# Resize an image in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, image, swift, watchos

I am currently following the courses: "The Complete Apple Watch Development course - 14 Build apps" by Yohann Taieb on Stackskills, but I've hit a road block.

Whenever I insert an image in my storyboard, it is resized but when I run the app, the image is too tall or doesn't match the storyboard. I haven't found solution.

An example :

[image: imgur.com/mywEgUp]

**EDIT:**
This probleme was solved in the Xcode 7 beta 5 ;)

Comment: How you tryed seting the frame programatically, or using constraints in storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is an issue of content mode. Try changing it to "Aspect Fit", which will keep the aspect ratio of the image and fit it to the frame of the containing image view.

Comment: (I specify I use Xcode Version 7.0 beta and watchOS 2)